# How to assign existing Core Data object to property of another Core Data object?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

If I search for a `Customer` object and I find the customer exists, then I want to assign that `Customer` object to the `invoice.customer` property of a new `Invoice` object. Can I do the following?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext]];
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults=NO; //populate beverage object
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@)", customerID];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [self.objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if([array count] == 1) 
{
    invoice.customer = (Customer*)[array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

What I want to avoid is having to re-assign all the property values of the `Customer` to `invoice.customer`. Are there any considerations when doing this?

Comment: Can you edit your post to detail the relationship between Invoice and Customer? That's really the key to answering your question.